# search list objects inside strings using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list of string like this

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
```

For example my list is

```
{one , two , three , four , five}
```

In database I have a `string` like this

```
"five-six-seven-eight"
```

How I can use Linq to SQL to search between my string in database and my list. For example my query search should be true because "five" is common on both. 
My query is this:

```
var q = from p in m.ViewAbuseReports where
 (list1.Contains(p.Abuse.ToString().Split('-')) || list1.Count == 0)
    select new
    {
        Col2 = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
        Col3 = p.DateTakhalof,
        Col4 = p.DateReturn
    };
```

Comment: I didn't get the question, would you kindly clarrify some more.

Comment: Seems like you need LINQ `Intersect`

Comment: @Ovis I want to search a list of string in a string , My string in database splitted with "-"

Comment: @Ian would you please give me some example ?

Comment: @mosyflasher example added. Let me know if that fits what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using LINQ `Intersect`.

```
var q = from p in m.ViewAbuseReports
 let ps = p.Abuse.ToString().Split('-')
 let i = list1.Intersect(ps).ToList() //here you get if there is any intersect (common elements) between the two `IEnumerable`
 where (i.Count > 0 || list1.Count == 0)
 select new
 {
    Col2 = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
    Col3 = p.DateTakhalof,
    Col4 = p.DateReturn
 };
```

Comment: `Intersect` will not work with local collection in LinQToSQL.

Comment: @mosyflasher great! Glad that my solution fits your need. ;)

Comment: But we should consider that use .AsEnumerable() to work

Comment: @mosyflasher use `.AsEnumberable()`? @.@?

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from p in m.ViewAbuseReports where
(list1.Any(l => p.Abuse.ToString().Contains(l)) || list1.Count == 0)
select new
{
    Col2 = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
    Col3 = p.DateTakhalof,
    Col4 = p.DateReturn
};
```

If any of the strings in `list1` is in `p.Abuse` this will be true. This way you don't have to take care of splitting the string (which would be a hard thing to do in database).